# In bootstrap-vue make responsive listing of items

Tags: responsive, bootstrap-vue

With bootstrap-vue, I make listing of items and I need to make items in 2 columns in big devices.
Looks like

```
<b-container  fluid="sm" v-for="nextAd in ads" :key="nextAd.id">
        <div style="border: 2px dotted green">
        {{ nextAd.id }}=>{{ nextAd.title }}
            </div>
    </b-container>
```

But I failed, as I have always items in 1 column.
Which way is correct ?

```
"bootstrap-vue": "^2.1.0"
"vue": "^2.6.10"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to utilize bootstraps [grid](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/layout/#how-it-works) system if you want a responsive list of items.

```js
new Vue({
 el: "#app"
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.2.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <b-container>
    <b-row>
      <b-col cols="12" sm="6" v-for="i in 10">
        <!-- Only adding this div with a background to highlight the columns -->
        <div class="bg-dark text-white">
          Item {{ i }}
        </div>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
```